# Django auth.authenticate() returning NONE in auto login

Tags: django, authentication

This is my code for autologin after registration.

```
def authenticationRegister(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        registrationForm = MyRegistrationForm(request.POST)
        if registrationForm.is_valid():
            user_present = registrationForm.save()
            request.session['RegistrationForm_error'] = None
            username = request.POST.get('username', '')
            password = request.POST.get('password', '')
            user = auth.authenticate(username=username,password=password)
            if user is not None:
                auth.login(request,user)
                request.session['username'] = user.email
                request.session['id'] = user.id
            return HttpResponseRedirect('/home/')
        else:
            request.session['RegistrationForm_error'] = registrationForm.errors
            return HttpResponseRedirect('/authenticate/')
    return HttpResponseRedirect('/authenticate/')
```

The problem with this code is that auth.authenticate() is returning None. 
When I put my user.login() statement outside if then the Anonymous User error appears. 
The form is getting saved in db. but auth.authenticate() is returning None.

Code for MyRegistrationForm

```
class MyRegistrationForm(UserCreationForm):
    error_messages = {
    'duplicate_email': _("A user with that email already exists."),
    'password_mismatch' : _("The two password fields didn't match."),
    }

    username = forms.CharField(
        widget = forms.TextInput(attrs={'placeholder':'Enter Username','class': 'form-control input', 'size': '20'}),
        help_text = _("Required. 30 characters or fewer. Letters, digits and @/./+/-/_ only."))
    email = forms.EmailField(
        widget = forms.TextInput(attrs={'placeholder': 'Email', 'class': 'form-control input', 'size': '20'}))
    password1 = forms.CharField(
        widget = forms.PasswordInput(attrs={'placeholder': 'Password','class': 'form-control input', 'size': '20'}))
    password2= forms.CharField(
        widget = forms.PasswordInput(attrs={'placeholder': 'Confirm Password','class': 'form-control input', 'size': '20'}),
        help_text = _("Enter the same password as above, for verification."))

    class Meta:
        model = get_user_model()
        fields = ('username', 'email', 'password1', 'password2')

    def clean_email(self):
        email = self.cleaned_data["email"]
        try:
            get_user_model()._default_manager.get(email=email)
        except get_user_model().DoesNotExist:
            return email
        raise forms.ValidationError(
            self.error_messages['duplicate_email'],
            code = 'duplicate_email',)

    def save(self, commit=True):
        user = super(MyRegistrationForm, self).save(commit=False)
        user.set_password(self.cleaned_data["password1"])
        if commit:
            user.save()
        return user

    def clean_password2(self):
        password1 = self.cleaned_data.get("password1")
        password2 = self.cleaned_data.get("password2")
        if password1 and password2 and password1 != password2:
            raise forms.ValidationError(self.error_messages['password_mismatch'], code = 'password_mismatch', )
        return password2
```

Comment: Please show the code for MyRegistrationForm.

Comment: Why are you fetching the username and password from the POST data instead of the form's cleaned data. Have you tried printing those values to make sure they are what you expect?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't have a key in the POST data called `password`, because your password fields are `password1` and `password2`. So your dict `get` is simply returning the default value, the empty string.

As Alasdair says in the comments, you should be using the form cleaned_data anyway. And since you can only get to that point if the form is valid, you know that the values exist, so you shouldn't be using `get` with a default: just use the standard dict access.

```
        username = form.cleaned_data['username']
        password = form.cleaned_data['password1']
```